# The purpose of using SQL Server triggers on views

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using a trigger on a table is looks familiar to me and its not clear that how and its purpose, to use a trigger on a view .Do we have some benefits having trigger on a view instead of a table ? Could you please explain that the purpose of using triggers on Views?

Comment: I disagree with those close-voters voting for a move to DBA - this sounds like a question about database *development* which is perfectly on-topic for here - though it may be closable for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as possible, Views and Tables should be treated as interchangeable objects - you should be able to replace a Table with a View (or vice versa) and not have to make any changes to any client code that makes use of the object.

So any reason you might have for putting a trigger on a table could also be valid for placing a trigger on a view.

However, there are certain circumstances where you *need* to put trigger(s) on a view that would not be necessary for a table. These occur where, due to the view definition, it is not possible for the system to make the view updatable (can be the target of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE) automatically.

In such a circumstance, if you want the view to be updatable, it's up to you to write triggers for the view to implement the correct set of changes against the base tables manually.